# Asp.net MVC 2: Is it possible to call a specific action of a controller for a User Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm just begin upgrade my asp.net site from Webform to MVC 2. So far it's more clear and lighter than Webform. I'm stucking on the part of rending an User Control in different actions.

My User Control named `Banner.ascx` is placed in `Site.Master`. This `Banner.ascx` get url from `DataView["BannerUrl"]` which is set in HomeController > Index action. This will run OK when I point URL to `/Home/Index`. Now I want this `Banner.ascx` control get DataView only from HomeController > Index whatever action I'm pointing to, for example when point URL to /Article/Detail/1 I want the `Banner.ascx` run action Index of HomeConttroller to get `DataView["BannerUrl"]`

Any response is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the MVC Controller the same way you would call any other server-side code.  You can access the registered `IControllerFactory` instance via `ControllerBuilder.GetControllerFactory()`.  Then you can use the controller factory to get an initialized instance of the `IController` instance by passing it the route values in the `RouteData` of the `RequestContext` parameter (these would be `controller = "Home"` and `action = "Index"`.  `IController.Execute()` will then execute the Action the same way that the MVC life cycle would if it received a request.

Comment: Thanks. I can create controllerFactory and instantiate a HomeController. How can I pass action name into the context when its values are read only? I use `var context = ((MvcHandler)HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler).RequestContext;`

Comment: You pass the action name by RouteData.Values["action"]